# Evidence of source of funds as a student

Tags: visas, uk, proof-provenance-of-funds

As a student applying for a tourist visa to the UK and attaching bank statements, can you use Western Union, MoneyGram, and World Remit receipts from family and friends who sent the money to prove to the ECO your sources of income?

Comment: See [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) Documentation such as you describe seems to be unlikely to tell a story they want to hear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to explain who pays for your visit *and why*. For tourist visa, the money must be a genuine gift and not a *loan* or *investment* that you are expected to repay at a later date. If it is a loan, the visa officials will assume that you intend to work in the UK to repay it.

So the question will be why your family and friends would give you the money. You must show that they earn enough themselves to give you the money.