# Proof to show what is the origin of money sent to me as a gift from family members or friends in my bank account

Tags: visas, uk

Is it required to get a a letter from the donor (family member or a friend) confirming and giving details of sending you money, which they sent to help you fund your tourist visa?

Could it also be the letter used as evidence attached to my personal bank statement as a proof to the Entry Clearance Officer to show what is the origin of the money?

Comment: If someone has given a sum of money, a letter from the donor stating the amount and the reason will be useful as evidence supporting the corresponding deposit in your account. More important will be a copy of the donor's bank statement showing the corresponding withdrawal. Without it, the letter will have little credibility. Even with these documents, the ECO may give little weight to the evidence, because the whole arrangement could be a sham: the purported gift might actually be a loan. I do not know actual practice in such cases, so I am posting this as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: I edited the question, if it's reviewed please let me know if I didn't change the meaning. I understand you're from Ghana and travelling to UK?

Comment: @kuba,thus okay and thanks for the correction,but you also have anything to add to what phoog said

Comment: How is this question different from what [you asked several days ago](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/86598/evidence-of-source-of-funds-as-a-student)?

Comment: Ethan unfortunately not, I just wanted to make the question clearer.

Comment: @Dorothy,vast difference this one is monies received from family or friends is advisable to let them write a letter detailing the gift they gave together with the money transaction receipts,and that to show the origin of where the money is from,dont know if you get it me right

Comment: @EthanElisha And the other one was also about what is needed to document money from friends and family. I see no "vast difference".